# How to pause animation after page has been refreshed

Tags: android

I have an activity with `ListView` data which is been animated when an activity is created. The Animation - it slides the list row from bottom to top just like that of google animation. I am also reloading the page by using the `swipeRefreshLayout`, when the page is refreshed, the animation effect is executed, that is by moving the first positioned row from bottom to top.

I want the animation effect to be executed only when the page has been created for the first time, this means that when the page is reloaded the animation effect(thats the movement of the first row from bottom to top) should not be executed.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    refreshContent();
            }
        });
}


...

private int lastPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    Animation animation =
        AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, (position > lastPosition)
            ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
            : R.anim.down_from_top);
    v.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    return v;
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The 'mSwipeRefreshLayout' would be the "parent" in the 'getView()' method, wouldn't it?

Comment: @0X0nosugar No it is not the "parent" in the 'getView()' method

Comment: ok, thanks. I think my solution will work anyway. I'm writing it down right now.

Comment: @0X0nosugar Very well Sir

Comment: It would be rather awkward to do resume animation after refresh. Instead, I suggest you to declare animation instance in class (not inside the method) and do animation.cancel() to stop it before calling refreshContent().

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag on the parent to mark you've done the animation and check for the tag before starting the animation
(assuming the parent has no tag set):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    // check the tag (but don't call "toString()" on a null reference)
    if (parent.getTag() == null || !parent.getTag().toString().equals("X") )
    {
        Animation animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, (position > lastPosition)
            ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
            : R.anim.down_from_top);

        v.startAnimation(animation);

        parent.setTag("X");
    }
    // not sure whether the next statement has to go into the if-block:
    lastPosition = position;

    return v;
}
```

Comment: This disables the animation effect even when the page has first been created

Comment: @George - so you wanted more than row to be animated?

Comment: I want all the rows to be animate only when the activity has been created for the first time, and to also deactivate the animation when the page has been refreshed

Comment: @George  - then you need to set the tag based on that condition. I can't tell you where exactly because I don't see very much of your code. But basically the concept is: start the animations only if the ViewGroup holding the rows does not have the "X" marker set. And set the marker as soon as you know you want the animations to stop.

Comment: The condition  `if(parent.getTag() == null || !parent.getTag().toString().equals("X")) ` should have executed the animation when the page has first been created, but in this case it stops the animation

Comment: @George - but the if block (like in my answer) gets executed once, doesn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94680/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-george).

Comment: I've found something for API >= 21, check out the chat if you like

Comment: @George - looks like the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94680/discussion-between-0x0nosugar-and-george) is still open. See you there :)